# How to customize SQLite Connection String to specific path?

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, connection-string

I'm writing a desktop application using VS2015 + WPF + SQLite + EF6. My connection string looks like the following:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="WPTContext" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|WPT.sqlite" providerName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I'd like to put the database file to `(User folder)\Local\MyApp\File.sqlite`. How should I configure the connection string, such that application seeks for the database file in that specific folder?